# How can i retrieve my old data after rollback in postgres and ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql-9.1

I recently accidnetally rolled back a migration using step method. after running db:migrate again all my data was gone like it is supposed. is it possible to retrieve this data.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from a mailing list about the subject:

The first thing to do is shut down postgresql and take a full backup of 
the data directory, including any archived WAL you might have (files in 
pg_xlog). Make sure this is done first.

Next, do you have any backups? If you have a base backup from before the 
delete, and all the WAL files from the time of the base backup until 
now, then you can try point-in-time recovery to the point right before 
the data loss:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/continuous-archiving.html

If not, are we talking about a single row, or many rows? If it's a 
single row you might be able to do some manual steps, like examining the 
pages to recover the data.

Another option is to try pg_resetxlog (make sure you have a safe backup 
first!):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgresetxlog.html

And try setting the current transaction ID to just before the delete 
ran. Then you may be able to use pg_dump or otherwise export the deleted 
rows.

You can read more here: http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Recover-rows-deleted-td5710305.html

Comment: Let me try it out. Get back to you